Please help! I sent 0.00005BTC from a Ledger device to my Tangem but after confirming, I see it sent my whole BTC balance to an unknown address. How?
I was planning to move my entire BTC balance from my Ledger Nano X over to a Tangem wallet and first wanted to do a test transaction for just 0.00005 BTC. In Ledger Live on my PC I manually entered the receiving address and the amount, no copy/paste. So AFTER confirming the transaction on the Nano X and I definitely remember seeing the amount (0.00005) I saw that the address it was actually sent to on the block explorer was completely different to the one I put in Ledger Live AND worst of all it moved my entire BTC balance to that address! I'm baffled how this could even happen and freaking out that it's now gone unless I'm not understanding something about the process. If anyone has any idea if my scenario is a known thing, maybe used by scammers, or knows what might have happened just so I have some certainty it would be a great help.

This question is similar to: Why are there two transaction outputs when sending to one address?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Did all your money go to a single output that was different from the one you were trying to send to, or did the payment you were making go through and the rest went to a change address in your own wallet?

Hi Murch, this is the transaction ID ec5e8f16380ac2a22975767b84465b2c83cb442622d3d3b359a549f41c20effd. No mention of the amount I confirmed to send (0.00005 BTC). Instead it sent my whole balance which was exactly 1BTC and the output address bc1q6ct7xcqx6la4x2jnrdhc6s4zgku8sf5y0fn7sz is unknown to me. The output address for Tangem I entered into Ledger Live was bc1qc93vvkuq84sjggh49n90z3ga9jzkemfqdz6hgv. I really hope I'm missing something bc I'm freaking out as to how this could even happen.

I've since read on this forum that if bc1q6ct7xcqx6la4x2jnrdhc6s4zgku8sf5y0fn7sz is actually a change address, then how do I access it?
